# regex match anything ends with but not contains a sequence

Tags: regex

I'm using regex to extract json data in html and and i cannot find how to get text ends with '});' but not include it.

Here is a sample data:

```
start({"main":{"ss_service":"...();"}});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not decode the json?! :S

Comment: @Dekel because they don't have JSON yet?

Comment: `...(?:}\);)`? .......

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking encountered for a very long code, any thoughts?